# SQL Server query returns duplicate results because of multiple group by columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, distinct, sql-server-2014

Here is my query :

```
select
    Booking.BookingID, Booking.BookingNo, 
    Booking.Vcode, Booking.TransID, 
    Booking.StatusID,Booking.BookingDate,
    BookingContact.FirstName, BookingContact.MiddleName, BookingContact.LastName, 
    Schedule.DepatureDateTime as DepartDate, 
    Origin.City as Origin, Destination.City as Destination, 
    PaxJourney.TripTypeID
from 
    Booking
inner join 
    Pax on Booking.BookingID = Pax.BookingID  
inner join 
    PaxJourney on Pax.PaxID = PaxJourney.PaxID 
inner join 
    Schedule on PaxJourney.ScheduleID = Schedule.ScheduleID
inner join 
    City as Origin on Schedule.DepartureCityID = Origin.CityID
inner join 
    City as Destination on Schedule.ArrivalCityID = Destination.CityID
inner join 
    BookingContact on Booking.BookingID = BookingContact.BookingID
group by 
    Booking.BookingID ,Booking.BookingNo, Booking.Vcode, Booking.TransID, 
    Booking.StatusID,Booking.BookingDate, BookingContact.FirstName, 
    BookingContact.MiddleName, BookingContact.LastName, 
    Schedule.DepatureDateTime, Origin.City, Destination.City, PaxJourney.TripTypeID
```

**Question**: how to remove multiple group by fields in my query?

I got duplicate data because of these two "Origin.City, Destination.City" columns when I remove any one column in group by section I got error :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>   Column 'City.City' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I want to use group by with one column like "group by Booking.BookingID"

Comment: You remove them from both the `select` and the `group by`.  Beyond that, it is impossible to say what you want, because you have no description of what you want the query to do, desired results, or sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to use a aggregation function, as the error stated. All columns you won't group, must use an aggregation.

If you have only a group by based on `Booking.BookingId` you need to use an aggregation function on all other columns you select. For example:

```
SELECT Booking.BookingId, MAX(City.City) as City
FROM Booking
GROUP BY Booking.BookingId
```

Even if all rows of `City.City` show the same value, SQL Server won't execute your query, as it *may* occur a duplicate value with different contents. This way you need to define the proper aggregation (e.g. `MIN`,`MAX`,`AVG`, etc.) on all not grouped columns.

Comment: Nice to help you. If this is your solution, you can mark it as your answer and/or upvote it, it will help others to find the solution faster. By the way, welcome to stack overflow.